# How do you add an icon overlay to folders icons in Source Control Explorer?

Tags: tfs, vsx

I am interested in marking folders as Active, Archived, and Released in Source Control Explorer so it is easier for the team to see which branches are active. I am somewhat familiar with VSX so once I know where to start I can make progress, but I need help with where to start.

An example of what I want to do is VisualSVN which places a status of the files in Solution Explorer. I am unsure if TFS will allow me to set a property on the folder so that if the folder is moved that status will move with it. If I have to I could create a file called BranchStatus.xml and read that file to set the icon.

If you know which namespaces and VSX/DTE objects I should look into on MSDN please let me know. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I got word from a developer on the Team Foundation Server team and he said there is no extensibility point for replacing icons in this way. (via Twitter - http://twitter.com/bubbafat/status/1729485103)

There has to be a way to warn a developer that a branch is archived and should not be used for current development. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no. The TFS team confirmed there is not extensibility for the Source Control Explorer in VS2008. There may be this option in VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

What we have decided to do is move the branch into a folder named Archive once we release the next version. This way everyone knows it's just there for historical reference.

Comment: This is what we chose to do on our team as well. In VS 2010 there may be options to set a status on the folder/branch but there will not be any extension points like exist in the Solution Explorer. :(

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment:

Just as an idea.  Using the command line you can setup and modify workspaces for anyone (if you have sufficient privileges).  I thing it is also be possible to cloak a branch for other workspaces (ie your co-workers).

The stuff could still be accessed if needed, but would not be automatically retrieved.

Not as good as what you were going for, but it could work...

Vaccano